# What is the fastest way to find out the each size of more over 50,000,000 files

Tags: linux, bash, command

I want to create a file list for backup, So I tried using the "du" command, but there is no result even after waiting a day.

du -BG -d 1 -a /TARGET_DIR

What is the fastest way to find out the each size of more over 50,000,000 files (result files of bio analysis pipelines.) under a specific directory(It includes many sub-dir)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the fact that the command does not finish. Could it be that `/TARGET_DIR` is mounted on a network and there are access problems? What happens if you leave out the directory completely (which would have `du` search your working directory)?

Comment: As an alternative to `du`, consider the `find` command, in particular its `-size` option.

Comment: Maybe 1 day is too short. Calculating `50e6/86400` (files/sec_of_day) you get ~579. The means, if the command scans less than 579 files per second, it needs more then 1 day for scanning 50,000,000 files.

Comment: I made 2 tests. First I scanned a file system with 60000 files. It is mounted locally and was not cached at start. It scanned ~12000 files/sec. Second I scanned a mounted NFS file system of medium fast server (1GBit ethernet). I scanned about 100 files/sec. In this case the scanning of 50mio files will need 5.8 days.

Answer (score 0):

du stand for Disk Usage

du report block used by files, not exactly the file size.

For having file size, prefer use of stat command

```
stat --printf="%s" myfile
```

just stat files in a for loop on your directory

For a large amount of file i guess coding a command in C language will be better.